# Cross domain requests from the server

Tags: security, http, webserver, cross-domain, httprequest

I know that browsers often prevent cross domain http requests to servers due to security measures (which can be avoided by CORS or JSONP), but what about a server making an http request to another server? Can that be blocked by security restrictions?

I guess what I'm asking is that since the server is making the request and not the browser, would I still need to deal with things such as CORS and/or JSONP, or are those work arounds specifically geared towards browser-level security?

Answer (score 2):

A computer is free to send whatever requests it wants.

In the case of CORS, that's one piece of software (the browser) restricting less trusted code (Javascript) running on the same computer. But if you have full access to the computer you can do anything.

It is a browser specific measure designed to deal with the fact that people often run untrusted code in their browser and sensibly want to restrict it. More specifically, the Same Origin Policy causes the restriction and CORS is a way around it for participating servers due to the need for legitimate cross site AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Blocked by *whose* security restrictions? Of course it *could* be, but not by the user. A server making an HTTP request to another web server is no different than your browser making the same request.